# How to search PyDev's bug tracker?

Tags: pydev

PyDev uses [Brainwy Tracker](https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/) as its bug tracker. How do I search that databaes, e.g. for "variable view"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "Filter" text field in the top bar? I just tried it, and it correctly searches for the given words in title and comments.